# What is the regex for extracting @[1-99] from a string?

Tags: regex

I am given this string

@12 RegExr was created by gskinner.com, and is proudly hosted by Media Temple. @42 @20 @1 @w w@32 #$@22 w@5 @2 @10.

I have to extract substring with this pattern `@[1-99]`. so for the given string, the result should be @12 @42 @20 @1 @2 @10

I tried this pattern `\B@([1-9]|[1-9][0-9])\b`  but it did take `#$@12` where it should not.
what is the regex for that?

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten the pattern making the second character class optional, and assert a whitespace boundary to the left

```
(?<!\S)@([1-9][0-9]?)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CicnFJ/1)

Comment: it works for the given string but then I try other test cases: @92&( and  @33rd and it fails. the regex pattern still detect these substrings